# Why does my RouteHandler break my route namespaces?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using a convention where I have a web api endpoint at a url like `/api/product/{action}` and a conventional MVC test page at the corresponding url `api/test/product/{action}`.  Api and Test have their own namespaces, so the api controller is `MyApp.Controllers.Api.ProductController` namespace while the test controller is `MyApp.Controllers.Api.Test.ProductController`.

This works fine, except that I need to specify namespaces so that the framework knows which controller to use, `Api` or `Test`, when a request is made.  So, I have the following routes:

```
    Dim r1 = routes.MapRoute _
        (
            "DefaultWebApiTest",
            "api/test/{controller}/{action}",
            {"MyApp.Controllers.Api.Test"}
        )

    Dim r2 = routes.MapHttpRoute _
    (
        "DefaultWebApi",
        "api/{controller}/{action}"
    )
```

But I recently needed to add a RouteHandler, and told the route about it:

```
    r2.RouteHandler = New HyphenatedRouteHandler  <--this is causing trouble
```

As soon as I did this, it broke the namespacing; a request for `/api/product/{action}` that used to be correctly routed to `MyApp.Controllers.Api.ProductController`, started going instead to `MyApp.Controllers.Api.Test.ProductController`, which is totally wrong.

I know I could avoid this by just changing controller names so there was no collision and need for explicit namespacing, but I don't really want to, and I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my `HyphenatedRouteHandler` was inheriting from `MvcRouteHandler`, and it seems that `MvcRouteHandler` only looks for objects of type `Controller` and **not** `ApiController`.  So it was only seeing my `Api.Test` controller, because the `Api` controller was of the wrong time.

This is reasonable if you realize that Api and Mvc are often different in ways like this, except that there are a lot of ways where they do share the same functionality, and it's not always obvious which is which.  This took me a whole day of troubleshooting to figure out.

If you want to have a route handler for WebApi, instead of MVC, you need to inherit the handler from **`HttpControllerRouteHandler`** instead.